# Finding in between which two dates in a column the target date is

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Got a table that I am trying to clean up and can't figure out how to find a record where one date falls between two dates in the actual columns

```
TargetDateTime         Location      TransferDateTime

01/01/2014 1:00 PM     Room 1        01/01/2014 10:00 AM
01/01/2014 1:00 PM     Room 2        01/01/2014 12:30 PM
01/01/2014 1:00 PM     Room 3        01/01/2014 01:30 PM
01/01/2014 1:00 PM     Room 4        01/01/2014 03:00 PM
```

TransferDateTime marks the time when a person was moved to the room
TargetDateTime marks some event that a person did.

In this example, TargetDateTime is 1:00 PM; therefore the event took place in Room 2 because 1:00 PM falls between 12:30 PM and 1:30 PM.
What would be the best way in SQL to select only that row and ignore the rest?

Thanks a bunch for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample data and guessing that you have groups of the same `TargetDateTime`, the following should do it.

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT  TargetDateTime,
            Location,
            TransferDateTime
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TargetDateTime ORDER BY TransferDateTime) AS rn
    FROM    TableName
    WHERE   TransferDateTime >= TargetDateTime 
)
SELECT * 
FROM   MyCTE 
WHERE  rn = 1
```